# Paramiko works but Fabric fails (asking for password)

Tags: fabric, paramiko

I searched around and I really couldn't get an answer on this but for some reason, fabric keeps asking for password but paramkio doesn't

```
import paramiko

mykey = paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key_file('/path/to/key')     

client = paramiko.SSHClient()
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

client.connect('<ip>', username='me', pkey=mykey)
(stdin, stdout, stderr) = client.exec_command('ls /home') #works
for line in stdout.readlines():
  print line

client.close()
```

But fabric doesn't

```
from fabric.api import sudo

env.user = 'me'
env.hosts = 'ip'
env.key_filename = '/path/to/key'

def run():
  sudo('ls') #asks for password
```

Also, direct `ssh` for that user works. So does `scp`. So it can't be public key or ssh agent issues.

Anyone know what is going on with Fabric?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in this line:

```
  sudo('ls') #asks for password
```

Fabric asks you for password to execute command on remote host as sudo,
so try to change sudo() to run().

If you still want to use sudo but without password, then I suggest searching for settung up passwordless sudo, but still only for specific commands only.